# Performance Issue while deleting records

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a simple delete statement like this:

```
DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ATTR_NAME='Something'.
```

This has to delete around **6,00,000** rows which is taking more than half an hour. 
I have three columns in the table in which the combination of `ID,ATTR_NAME` is a Primary Key.The third column is of `CLOB` type. The table contains around *21 million Records* . There are no separate indexes for any column. There are no triggers and no foreign key references.

This is not the one time process. I need to do on regular intervals.

I doubt this is because of the `primary key` which is in turn creating the index and thus leading to more time. Please correct me if I was wrong. Should I try removing the PK, or disabling the index? I heard I should disable the indices while inserting and deleting. I can't simply test, because this is production machine and I need to ask permission to remove. Please share your valuable suggestions

And In General Does the Indexes affect all the DML statements?

Comment: You could try bulk delete (see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html) but don't expect magical results: deleting a huge number of rows is always slow. Another option is partioning your table on attr_name and drop the whole partition instead of deleting.

Comment: How many rows are in the table before the delete?  Are you deleting a large fraction of the rows?  Or a small fraction of the rows?  Is there an index on `attr_name`?  Are there triggers on the table?  Are there foreign keys in other tables that point to this table?  Are the foreign keys in these child tables indexed?

Comment: @StephaneM Bulk delete probably won't help here.  `FORALL` is an improvement over row-by-row processing but a single SQL statement is usually the best option.

Comment: btw, those CLOBs can store a lot of data, esp 6 million of them.  Is this a one-time thing?  Or are you trying to delete this much on some regular schedule?

Comment: A good answer to this question might be different depending on the purpose of the delete. If it's a one-off deletion (e.g. a datafix for an issue that has been resolved, so it's unlikely to be needed again in the future) then you might be better off batching the delete (e.g. add "WHERE ROWNUM < 100000" to the delete, commit, rinse & repeat until it finds no more rows to delete). Otherwise, a "soft delete" may be better (i.e. update the row with a "deleted" indicator).

Comment: Alternatively, if the table's purpose is only to hold temporary data, then a global temporary table *may* be a solution worth considering - that way you don't have to delete anything at all.

Answer (score 3):

If your index is `id,attr_name`, then that index cannot be used for your `where` clause, and the delete query has to do a full-table scan.

Index fields are used in `left->right` ordering, so your `id,attr_name` index would be used in these cases:

```
WHERE id = foo AND attr_name = bar
WHERE id = foo
WHERE attr_name = foo AND id = bar   // ordering within the where doesn't matter, but USAGE does
```

but not

```
WHERE attr_name = bar
```

because `id` is not present in that `where`.

You'll have to add a dedicated index on `attr_name`, or re-arrange your index so it's defined as `attr_name, id`. And of course, if the `id` field is your primary key, it should ALREADY have a PK index on it, making `id, attr_name` redundant.

Comment: This is not necessarily true.  Oracle is able to use indexes "out of order" with an [index skip scan](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/server.1111/e16638/optimops.htm#i51571).  Although unless the leading columns have few distinct values a skip scan probably won't help here.  This is why it's often useful to put the low-cardinality columns first (especially when combined with index compression).  But since this delete affects 6 million rows there's a good chance that index look ups won't be useful here anyway.

Comment: well, Oracle can use skip scan to skip the initial column if it wanted.  But if the amount of data to be deleted is a significant amount, then Oracle may choose to full scan anyway.

Comment: @JonHeller you type faster than me;)

Comment: -1. deleting 6 out of 21 million rows (~30%) will unlikely benefit from additional index (and there are no signs so far that full scan is a bottleneck). in fact, it will probably slow things down due to additional maintenance required during delete.

Answer (score 2):

[DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_parallel_ex.htm) is an easy way to significantly improve performance
 without altering any objects or significantly changing the process.

---

**Sample Schema**

```
--Create sample table.
create table my_table(id number, attr_name varchar2(100), a_clob clob);

--Insert 1 million rows.  Takes 31 seconds on my PC.
begin
    for i in 1 .. 10 loop
        insert /*+ append */ into my_table
        select level + i*100000, mod(level, 3), rpad('0', 100, '0')
        from dual
        connect by level <= 100000;
        commit;
    end loop;
end;
/

--Add primary key.
alter table my_table add constraint my_table_pk primary key (id, attr_name);
```

**Simple DELETE**

Deleting 1/3rd of the data with this simple method takes 86 seconds on my PC.

```
--Flush the cache.
alter system flush buffer_cache;

--Delete 1/3rd of the table.
delete from my_table where attr_name = 0;
rollback;
```

**DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE**

The parallel method ran only slightly faster on my machine.  Hopefully on a server with multiple CPUs and disks the difference will be larger.  This code
 is based on the example from the manual.

```
--Flush the cache.
alter system flush buffer_cache;

--Delete 1/3rd of the table.  Finished in 80 seconds.
begin
    --Create the TASK.
    dbms_parallel_execute.create_task ('mytask');

    --Chunk the table by ROWID.
    dbms_parallel_execute.create_chunks_by_rowid(
        task_name => 'mytask',
        table_owner => user,
        table_name => 'MY_TABLE',
        by_row => true,
        chunk_size => 1000);

    --Execute the DML in parallel.
    dbms_parallel_execute.run_task(
        task_name => 'mytask',
        sql_stmt => 
            'delete /*+ rowid(my_table) */ from my_table
            where rowid BETWEEN :start_id AND :end_id
                and attr_name = 0',
        language_flag => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
        parallel_level => 16);

    --Get the status.
    dbms_output.put_line('Status: '||dbms_parallel_execute.task_status('mytask'));

    --Done with processing; drop the task.
    dbms_parallel_execute.drop_task('mytask');
end;
/
```

**Pros and Cons**

This method requires a bit more code to do a simple DELETE, but it avoids these issues with other approaches:

1. An index access path almost certainly won't help if the DELETE affects 29% of the data.
2. Dropping and re-creating a primary key takes time, locks the table, and it's not always trivial to get accurate DDL.
3. Regular parallel DML will not work because of the CLOB column.
4. Partitioning or soft-deletes require changing the table structure.  (Although if possible these are probably the fastest methods.)

Comment: This is the best solution for large scale DML operations 11g onwards...

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of options to tune the statements.

- Partition table

  If ATTR_NAME column value is handful (which I guess is from your statement) you can consider partitioning the table (including CLOB - assume CLOB is not inline) and can simply drop the partition easily. You probably have to reorganize the indexes to be local indexes.
- Disable Index and rebuild after DELETE

  I suspect this really won't help - yes there is overhead on
  maintaining index but 600K is not a lot. Dropping and recreating
  index should be avoided.
- CTAS + Parallelism + DROP/RENAME + RECREATE INDEX

  The above would work if you have window to take DB offline for short period.

I wanted to try the option of updating the CLOB column to NULL for those records and issue delete subsequently. This is purely to measure if CLOB column is hogging the execution.